# friendly url mvc on RouteConfig file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This is how I try to make a friendly url to my site, where you can see all the news and then moving to my article.

i have try its here:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Index",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            },
            new
            {
                Url = UrlParameter.Optional,
                Id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

It should be like to use when he clicks on going he from the news and the article, the URL will look like this:

**www.helloworld.com/hello-world/1234**

The same should I do with the link when it is.
 i have try its here

```
@Html.ActionLink("Read more", "GetNew", "NewSite", new
    {
       url = item.url,
       id = item.Id,
       @class = "btn btn-3d btn-info mr-xs mb-sm pull-right"
    })
```

Comment: Have you tried attribute routing? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

Comment: I've tried and it makes no sense because it does not. @Locke125